# I want to share the content of my Activity by Share in the Action Bar

Tags: android, android-intent, toolbar

I want to share the content of my Activity by Share in the Action Bar. I was able to implement some steps but when I try to share, the content is not attached. Here's my code for review.

The content to be shared is in the ListList (ListManagementDetail, SubTitleManagementDetails, ListManagementDetails1, ListManagementDetails2, ListManagementDetails3,ListManagementDetails4,ListManagementDetails5);
 As the code shows.

```
package com.example.ronaldo.megareinooficial.PalavraPastoral;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ronaldo.megareinooficial.R;

public class Activity_Palavra_Pastoral_Detalhe extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView tituloMinistracaoDetalhe;
    private TextView subTituloMinistracaoDetalhe;
    private TextView paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe1;
    private TextView paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe2;
    private TextView paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe3;
    private TextView paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe4;
    private TextView paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe5;

    private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.palavra_pastoral_item_detalhe);

        tituloMinistracaoDetalhe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titulo_detalhe_ministracao);
        subTituloMinistracaoDetalhe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subTitulo_detalhe_ministracao);
        paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paragrafo_detalhe_ministracao1);
        paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paragrafo_detalhe_ministracao2);
        paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paragrafo_detalhe_ministracao3);
        paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paragrafo_detalhe_ministracao4);
        paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paragrafo_detalhe_ministracao5);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int position = intent.getIntExtra(Activity_Palavra_Pastoral.POSITION_MINISTRACAO, 0);

        ItemPalavraPastoralDetalhe itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe = Activity_Palavra_Pastoral.arrayListDetalheMinistracao.get(position);

        tituloMinistracaoDetalhe.setText(itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe.getTituloDetalheMinistracao());
        subTituloMinistracaoDetalhe.setText(itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe.getSubtituloDetalheMinistracao());
        paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe1.setText(itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe.getParagrafoDetalheMinistracao1());
        paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe2.setText(itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe.getParagrafoDetalheMinistracao2());
        paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe3.setText(itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe.getParagrafoDetalheMinistracao3());
        paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe4.setText(itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe.getParagrafoDetalheMinistracao4());
        paragrafoMinistracaoDetalhe5.setText(itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe.getParagrafoDetalheMinistracao5());

        setUpToobar();
    }

    // Método que cria o botão de menu do lado direito...
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        MenuItem sharedItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);

        // int i = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_eventos_detalhe).get

        shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(sharedItem);
        shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());

        return true;
    }

    private Intent getDefaultIntent(){

        Intent sharedeIntent = new Intent();
        sharedeIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        sharedeIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharedeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Teste");
        sharedeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Teste 01");

        return sharedeIntent;

    }
}
```

In case, I want to be able to share the contents of my arrayList. There are 5 paragraphs.

Comment: You posted a bunch of irrelevant code. And omitted code for extracting content from the lists. And code to attach content to the intent is missing to.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for the previous Activity ...

```
public class Activity_Palavra_Pastoral extends AppCompatActivity {

public final static String POSITION_MINISTRACAO = "com.example.ronaldo.megareinooficial.POSITION_MINISTRACAO";

private Toolbar toolbar;
private ListView listViewMinistracao;
private ListView listViewMinistracaoDetalhe;
private ListViewAdapterPalavraPastoral adapterMinistracoes;
private ListViewAdapterPalavraPastoralDetalhe adapterMinistracoesDetalhe;
public static ArrayList<ItemPalavraPastoralDetalhe> arrayListDetalheMinistracao;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.palavra_pastoral_list_activity);

    arrayListDetalheMinistracao = new ArrayList<ItemPalavraPastoralDetalhe>();
    listViewMinistracao = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.item_list_palavra_pastoral);
    listViewMinistracaoDetalhe = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.item_list_detalhe_palavra_pastoral);

    adapterMinistracoes = new ListViewAdapterPalavraPastoral(getApplicationContext());
    adapterMinistracoesDetalhe = new ListViewAdapterPalavraPastoralDetalhe(getApplicationContext());

    //Ministrações
    for (int i= 0; i<1; i++) {
        ministracao1(); ministracao2(); ministracao3();
        ministracao4(); ministracao5(); ministracao6();

        ministracaoDetalhe1(); ministracaoDetalhe2(); ministracaoDetalhe3();
        ministracaoDetalhe4(); ministracaoDetalhe5(); ministracaoDetalhe6();
    }

    listViewMinistracao.setAdapter(adapterMinistracoes);

    //Passando a posição da ministração pra abrir o detalhe da ministração
    listViewMinistracao.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent detalheMinistracao = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Palavra_Pastoral_Detalhe.class);
            //Enviando uma posiccao pra activity detalhe ministracao...
            detalheMinistracao.putExtra(POSITION_MINISTRACAO, position);
            startActivity(detalheMinistracao);
        }
    });

    setUpToobar();
}

public void ministracao1(){
    ItemPalavraPastoral itemPalavraPastoral = new ItemPalavraPastoral();
    itemPalavraPastoral.setImagemMinistracao(R.drawable.mauricio1);
    itemPalavraPastoral.setTituloMinistracao("Novo titulo 001");
    itemPalavraPastoral.setDataMinistracao("Nova DaTA 02/12/2016");

    adapterMinistracoes.addItem(itemPalavraPastoral);
}

// ********************************** MINISTRAÇÃO DETALHE ***********************************
public void ministracaoDetalhe1(){
    ItemPalavraPastoralDetalhe itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe = new ItemPalavraPastoralDetalhe();
    itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe.setTituloDetalheMinistracao("Libertos pra Libertar");
    itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe.setSubtituloDetalheMinistracao("Introdução: Salmos 126 foi escrito após o exilio de Israel. O povo estava esperimentando a tão sonhada libertação, depois do cativeiro na babilônia.");
    itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe.setParagrafoDetalheMinistracao1("Quando nos convertemos ficamos impactadas com o Reino de Deus, ficamos como quem sonha mesmo. Somos tomados pelo louvor, adoração e gratidão. As pessoas que estão ao nosso lado não entendem, que alguém rabugento, violento, possa da noite pro dia tornar-se uma pessoa amável e feliz.\n" +
            "Quando eles chegaram do cativeiro, tiveram também o impácto da terra abandona há 70 anos, em ruínas.");

    itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe.setParagrafoDetalheMinistracao2("Quando nos convertemos ficamos impactadas com o Reino de Deus, ficamos como quem sonha mesmo. Somos tomados pelo louvor, adoração e gratidão. As pessoas que estão ao nosso lado não entendem, que alguém rabugento, violento, possa da noite pro dia tornar-se uma pessoa amável e feliz.\n" +
            "Quando eles chegaram do cativeiro, tiveram também o impácto da terra abandona há 70 anos, em ruínas.");

    itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe.setParagrafoDetalheMinistracao3("Quando nos convertemos ficamos impactadas com o Reino de Deus, ficamos como quem sonha mesmo. Somos tomados pelo louvor, adoração e gratidão. As pessoas que estão ao nosso lado não entendem, que alguém rabugento, violento, possa da noite pro dia tornar-se uma pessoa amável e feliz.\n" +
            "Quando eles chegaram do cativeiro, tiveram também o impácto da terra abandona há 70 anos, em ruínas.");

    itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe.setParagrafoDetalheMinistracao4("Quando nos convertemos ficamos impactadas com o Reino de Deus, ficamos como quem sonha mesmo. Somos tomados pelo louvor, adoração e gratidão. As pessoas que estão ao nosso lado não entendem, que alguém rabugento, violento, possa da noite pro dia tornar-se uma pessoa amável e feliz.\n" +
            "Quando eles chegaram do cativeiro, tiveram também o impácto da terra abandona há 70 anos, em ruínas.");

    itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe.setParagrafoDetalheMinistracao5("Quando nos convertemos ficamos impactadas com o Reino de Deus, ficamos como quem sonha mesmo. Somos tomados pelo louvor, adoração e gratidão. As pessoas que estão ao nosso lado não entendem, que alguém rabugento, violento, possa da noite pro dia tornar-se uma pessoa amável e feliz.\n" +
            "Quando eles chegaram do cativeiro, tiveram também o impácto da terra abandona há 70 anos, em ruínas.");

    arrayListDetalheMinistracao.add(itemPalavraPastoralDetalhe);
}
```